# Keep acrylic when lost window focus on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 has a very cool acrylic effect, But this effect are only presente on focused windows. If a window lost it's focus, they becomes opaque and lost the acrylic effect.

Can I hack this behaviour and keep acrylic effect on for all 'non-focused' windows?